# React does not render the last hook update it received

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I've got a small hook that determines connectivity however while it updates from `false` to `true`, it never seems to render when that changes back to `false`. i.e. the logs show this:

```
Has stopped growing: false
Is connected: false
OFFLINESERVER: false
--------------------------
Has stopped growing: false
Is connected: true
OFFLINESERVER: true
--------------------------
Has stopped growing: false
Is connected: true
OFFLINESERVER: true
--------------------------
Has stopped growing: true
Is connected: true
OFFLINESERVER: false
--------------------------
```

but the UI shows the previous value, i.e.

[image]

If I add a simple count to the logs, I can see that the last logged value is `4` but the UI shows `3`, meaning the last received value is not getting rendered.

I've narrowed it down to this bit of code:

**App.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { useConnectionMonitor } from '../../src';

export default function App() {
  const source = 'https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt';
  const offlineHlsServer = useConnectionMonitor(source);

  console.log(`OFFLINESERVER: ${offlineHlsServer}`);
  console.log(`--------------------------`);
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{`Offline server is live: ${offlineHlsServer}`}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

**ConnectionMonitor.ts**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import usePrevious from './utils/usePrevious';

export const useConnectionMonitor = (source: string): boolean => {
  const [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [manifestLength, setManifestLength] = useState<number | null>(null);
  const previousManifestLength = usePrevious<number | null>(manifestLength);

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(async () => {
      const response = await fetch(source, {
        method: 'HEAD',
      });

      setIsConnected(response.ok);

      const length = response.headers.get('Content-Length');
      if (length) {
        setManifestLength(parseInt(length, 10));
      }
    }, 2000);

    return function cleanup() {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    };
  }, [source]);

  const hasStoppedGrowing = manifestLength !== null && manifestLength === previousManifestLength;
  console.log(`Has stopped growing: ${hasStoppedGrowing}`);
  console.log(`Is connected: ${isConnected}`);
  return isConnected && !hasStoppedGrowing;
};
```

In summary: the `console.log()` inside the App.tsx function clearly shows that the last received value is `false`. Why does the UI continue to show the previous value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because in your effect, when you call `setIsConnected`, it triggers a re-render (because you're changing state). However, if the only thing that changes is `hasStoppedGrowing` (like in the last console log), then it will not trigger a re-render because that is not part of the component's state.

You could change it so that you are setting the result of `isConnected && !hasStoppedGrowing` to the state inside your effect. Something like:

```
const [offlineHlsServer, setOfflineHlsServer] = useState<boolean>(false);

...

setOfflineHlsServer(isConnected && !hasStoppedGrowing);
return offlineHlsServer;
```

Comment: You're right, that does seem to make a difference! I now get the correct `false` value in the UI. I would have expected that a hook returning a new value would cause React to re-render the tree but it sounds like that's not the case.

Comment: Great! Yeah, "An update can be caused by changes to props or state." See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating